.net mvc project sdk package error: MSB4019: The imported project "../Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets " was not found
My project was working smoothly until a while ago I reopen it to find the following error when trying to build it (I'm using vs code)

I noticed sdk 8.0.107 being recently updated/implemented automatically not manually in my "Program Files" folder.
I'm not a pro in .Net and I'm still learning MVC, I went through a lot of stackoverflow posts / microsoft docs to try to understand what's happening and fix it, although I tried some simple solutions to see if they work and they didn't, but for other's I was scared to follow because I didn't want to go deep into a rabbit hole of attempted solutions to similar issues only to end up with even a more complicated issue.
Not only do I want to fix it, I also want to understand why it happened? how can I make sure this kind of issues won't happen again or at least be aware of them.
I really would appreciate any help.
Edit: I have found the solution that worked for me.
I'm keeping the post up in case someone ran into the same issue.

I suggest you could re-install the required SDK 8.0.106 from the .net SDK site to check it is fixed or not.  Besides, please share the dotnet --list-sdks result to see if you have other SDK version.

@BrandoZhang the sdks result are shown in the image
